# Can I assume my threads are done when threading.active_count() returns 1?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Given the following class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from time import sleep
import threading
from threading import active_count, Thread

class ScraperPool(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    Queue = []
    ResultList = []

    def __init__(self, Queue, MaxNumWorkers=0, ItemsPerWorker=50):
        # Initialize attributes
        self.MaxNumWorkers = MaxNumWorkers
        self.ItemsPerWorker = ItemsPerWorker
        self.Queue = Queue # For testing purposes.

    def initWorkerPool(self, PrintIDs=True):
        for w in range(self.NumWorkers()):
            Thread(target=self.worker, args=(w + 1, PrintIDs,)).start()
            sleep(1) # Explicitly wait one second for this worker to start.

    def run(self):
        self.initWorkerPool()

        # Wait until all workers (i.e. threads) are done.
        while active_count() > 1:
            print("Active threads: " + str(active_count()))
            sleep(5)

        self.HandleResults()

    def worker(self, id, printID):
        if printID:
            print("Starting worker " + str(id) + ".")

        while (len(self.Queue) > 0):
            self.scraperMethod()

        if printID:
            print("Worker " + str(id) + " is quiting.")

        # Todo Kill is this Thread.

        return

    def NumWorkers(self):
        return 1 # Simplified for testing purposes.

    @abstractmethod
    def scraperMethod(self): 
        pass

class TestScraper(ScraperPool):
    def scraperMethod(self):
        # print("I am scraping.")
        # print("Scraping. Threads#: " + str(active_count()))
        temp_item = self.Queue[-1]
        self.Queue.pop()

        self.ResultList.append(temp_item)

    def HandleResults(self):
        print(self.ResultList)

ScraperPool.register(TestScraper)

scraper = TestScraper(Queue=["Jaap", "Piet"])
scraper.run()
print(threading.active_count())
# print(scraper.ResultList)
```

When all the threads are done, there's still one active thread - `threading.active_count()` on the last line gets me that number.

The active thread is `<_MainThread(MainThread, started 12960)>` - as printed with `threading.enumerate()`.

Can I assume that all my threads are done when `active_count() == 1`?
Or can, for instance, imported modules start additional threads so that my threads are actually done when `active_count() > 1` - also the condition for the loop I'm using in the run method.

Comment: The `class TestScraper():` line is absent?

Comment: To keep things simple I only posted a part of the code. I've now added a pastebin link to the full script.

Comment: The code you post needs to be Minimal, Complete and Verifiable ([mcve]), and this seems to miss imports and definitions

Comment: Thanks. I hope my post is now up to par.

Comment: Imported modules can start background threads and so no, you can't wait until the thread count is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume that your threads are done when `active_count()` reaches 1. The problem is, if any other module creates a thread, you'll never get to 1. You should manage your threads explicitly.

Example: You can put the threads in a list and join them one at a time. The relevant changes to your code are:

```
def __init__(self, Queue, MaxNumWorkers=0, ItemsPerWorker=50):
    # Initialize attributes
    self.MaxNumWorkers = MaxNumWorkers
    self.ItemsPerWorker = ItemsPerWorker
    self.Queue = Queue # For testing purposes.
    self.WorkerThreads = []

def initWorkerPool(self, PrintIDs=True):
    for w in range(self.NumWorkers()):
        thread = Thread(target=self.worker, args=(w + 1, PrintIDs,))
        self.WorkerThreads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
        sleep(1) # Explicitly wait one second for this worker to start.

def run(self):
    self.initWorkerPool()

    # Wait until all workers (i.e. threads) are done. Waiting in order
    # so some threads further in the list may finish first, but we
    # will get to all of them eventually
    while self.WorkerThreads:
        self.WorkerThreads[0].join()

    self.HandleResults()
```

Comment: I was originally keeping track of the active scrapers in an integer `scraperpool.ActiveWorkersCount`, which got incremented/decremented when a worker started/stopped. I then ran into `threading.active_count()` and tried to use that method.

Is my original approach what you mean with "manage your threads"?

Comment: I don't think I quiet understand `threading.join()` yet, I'll have to look into that.
Could you given an example?

Comment: I'll post some code but it looks like what you want is already implemented in `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. You may want to check that out.

Comment: "joining" just means waiting for the thread to complete. Some thread objects are cleaned up under the covers so there is a minor technical reason for doing it, but mostly its just the way you make sure the thread has completed its work.

Answer (score 2):

according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate) `active_count()` includes the main thread, so if you're at 1 then you're most likely done, but if you have another source of new threads in your program then you may be done before `active_count()` hits 1.

I would recommend implementing explicit `join` method on your `ScraperPool` and keeping track of your workers and explicitly joining them to main thread when needed instead of checking that you're done with `active_count()` calls.

Also remember about GIL...

Comment: Its true that if you are at 1, you are done. But if any other module creates a thread, you'll never get to 1. That's what OP is asking.